# TransCAD file format for matrix data

Tags: linux, file-formats, shell, bash

I've never used TransCAD before. I have what I believe to be a TransCAD matrix file called `data.mtx` which I would like to be able to convert to some other file formats. I would prefer to do this at the Unix command line. I could use TransCAD directly to convert this to another format, but I'd like to be able to do this in an automated way via a shell script. I tried to search for TransCAD file formats and came across this page:

- [Map Your Own Data with TransCAD](http://www.caliper.com/TransCAD/MapYourData.htm)

Unfortunately I didn't see any occurrences of the strings 'matrix' or 'mtx'. Here is my first attempt at trying to understand what this file is:

```
$ file AM.mtx
AM.mtx: ARC archive data, squeezed

$ nomarch AM.mtx
nomarch: error reading data (hit EOF)
```

Some other stackexchange posts mentioned that the [FreeARC](http://freearc.org/) utility may succeed in extracting an ARC file where `nomarch` fails, but their download links seem to be dead.

So what's the deal? Is this not an ARC file? Is there some documentation on the TransCAD matrix format? Are there any open-source command-line tools for working with TransCAD files?